# The transaction failed during the simulation throwing error execution error in the contract at 0xf48f2b2d2a534e402487b3ee7c18c33aec0fe5e4

Tags: gnosis, timelock

We are testing gnosis safe to call a timelock contract function, it's stuck at gnosis safe, safe support says it's contract incompatibility, anyone knows a fix to this problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Not without taking a look at the code :/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.